# Why does the POSIX "printable characters" class not match a simple string?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, posix, non-printable

I wrote the following script to test the "printable characters" character class, as described [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html).

```
#!/bin/sh

case "foo" in
    *[:print:]*) echo "found a printable character" ;;
    *) echo "found no printable characters" ;;
esac
```

I expect this script to output `found a printable character`, at least one (in fact, all) characters in `"foo"` are printable. Instead, it outputs `"found no printable characters"`. Why are the characters in `"foo"` not recognized as printable characters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The string `[:` is only special *inside* a bracket expression and bracket expressions are themselves introduced by `[`.   So your example should be:

```
case "foo" in
    *[[:print:]]*) echo "found a printable character" ;;
    *) echo "found no printable characters" ;;
esac
```

If this seems cumbersome, think about for example how you would specify a pattern which should match a lowercase letter or a digit but not an upper case letter.

For more information see the [section of the POSIX spec detailing bracket expressions in regular expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05).   Bracket expressions in shell patterns are like bracket expressions in regular expressions, except for the treatment of `!` and `^`.  (Though otherwise there are other differences between shell patterns and regexes, outside the context of bracket expressions).